# How to attach boost::shared_ptr (or another smart pointer) to reference counter of object's parent?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, shared-ptr

I remember encountering this concept before, but can't find it in Google now.

If I have an object of type A, which directly embeds an object of type B:

```
class A {
    B b;
};
```

How can I have a smart pointer to `B`, e. g. `boost::shared_ptr<B>`, but use reference count of `A`? Assume an instance of `A` itself is heap-allocated I can safely get its shared count using, say, `enable_shared_from_this`.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, example would be message processing over TCP connection: to read from a socket you need to supply a contiguous buffer, but you want to be able to operate on discrete messages (queue them, pass them around). So you can either make extra copies of messages (takes twice as much memory, may cause fragmentation), or you can refcount the buffer in each every message's shared_ptr (if each message is a POD and maps directly to some spot in the buffer). This way, buffer will be deleted (or returned to the pool, etc) when last message's shared_ptr is destructed.

Comment: PS That is, if you can't hold a shared_ptr to a buffer in the message due to it needing to be a POD type.

Comment: Or if you are embedding some object into another one and use an API that expects a shared_ptr to embedded object (there may be multitude of reasons why you can't turn embedded object into heap-allocated one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'oh!

Found it right in `shared_ptr` documentation. It's called aliasing (see [section III of shared_ptr improvements for C++0x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm#aliasing)).

I just needed to use a different constructor (or a corresponding `reset` function overload):

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr( shared_ptr<Y> const & r, T * p );
```

Which works like this (you need to construct shared_ptr to parent first):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() : i_(13) {}
    int i_;
};

struct B {
    A a_;
    ~B() { std::cout << "B deleted" << std::endl; }
};

int
main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a;

    {
        boost::shared_ptr<B> b(new B);
        a = boost::shared_ptr<A>(b, &b->a_);
        std::cout << "ref count = " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "ref count = " << a.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a->i_ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @StephenNutt Even a conversion of `shared_ptr` to a derived class to a base class involves aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but you should be able to use a [custom deallocator object](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#allocator_constructor) to keep a shared_ptr to the parent around as long as the child is still needed. Something along these lines:

```
template<typename Parent, typename Child>
class Guard {
private:
   boost::shared_ptr<Parent> *parent;
public:
   explicit Guard(const boost::shared_ptr<Parent> a_parent) {
      // Save one shared_ptr to parent (in this guard object and all it's copies)
      // This keeps the parent alive.
      parent = new boost::shared_ptr<Parent>(a_parent);
   }
   void operator()(Child *child) {
      // The smart pointer says to "delete" the child, so delete the shared_ptr
      // to parent. As far as we are concerned, the parent can die now.
      delete parent;
   }
};

// ...

boost::shared_ptr<A> par;
boost::shared_ptr<B> ch(&par->b, Guard<A, B>(par));
```